# move from apache to nginx rewrite mod

Tags: nginx

I am moving from Apache to Nginx which is using vagrant and homestead box.
All of my project have individual .htaccess in the folder. We can share the config to my teammate easily with the individual .htaccess.

I manage to find apache .htaccess convert to nginx.

However, may I know in nginx is there anyway can work in .htaccess can override the config file setting?
I think it is troublesome for asking my team mate update their config file and they might not using nginx as well.

What is the nginx .htaccess file call?

As I research and read the documentation in nginx, all the rewrite config is done by nginx.conf.

Comment: There is no htaccess for nginx https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/likeapache-htaccess/

Comment: Yes. I know there no htaccess in nginx, so how do I share the rewrite mode config to other. with htaccess just a file to share among team mate. How to accomplish in nginx?